# Edit lead to maths not being displayed correctly, but rollback doesn't help

Tags: support, editing

I made a slight edit to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/29035/39599), but then some of the maths (which I did not edit) wasn't displaying correctly, so I rolled back the edit. However, the sections that weren't displaying properly did not return to their original state.

> Is it just me, or does the answer not display properly? If it doesn't display properly, why has my edit had this effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was a number of extra backslashes. There were two instead of one for each `\{` and triple instead of double at the ends of some lines `\\`. It all displays fine now.

This sometimes happens when using an outside editor. They sometimes quote backslashes this way.

Comment: Ah, that was an old answer the OP touched, which was written at a time when backslash entry was hack-y. See [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/813), among other old threads.

Comment: @J.M.: Interesting. Things work differently on different sites. How confusing.